# Send image to socket through html form

Tags: python, sockets, http

I am trying to send image through html form upload to my python socket.
The form is:

```
<form name="image-upload" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form- data">
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

How do I access this image in my python server through http socket?

Server will be something like this, it will receive the image, do some processing on it and return response according to that image.

```
HOST, PORT = '', 8888

my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
my_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
my_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
my_socket.listen(1)

while True:

    client_connection, client_address = my_socket.accept()
    request = client_connection.recv(1024)

    #here I will have code to get image
    #processing on image

    response = "Image received"
    http_response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n"+"Content-Type: text/html\n"+"\n"+"<html><body><h1>"+response+"</h1></body></html>\n"
    client_connection.sendall(http_response)
    client_connection.close()
```

Comment: You need to properly parse the HTTP request header and extract and parse the MIME in the HTTP request body. Since you obviously want to do it all by yourself on the socket instead of using higher level libraries you need to read and understand several RFC documents which describe the different parts. Start with RFC 2616 (HTTP) and RFC 2388 (multipart/form-data). Apart from that your HTTP response does not adhere to the standards (uses `\n` instead of `\r\n`) even if it will probably be understood by the forgiving parsing inside the browser.

Comment: Is there a reason as to why you want to use low-level sockets instead of a library that can handle the HTTP parsing for you? Something like [`bottle`](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html) or [`flask`](http://flask.pocoo.org/) will be much easier to use. If you must remain with the standard library you might look at [`http.server`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#module-http.server)

Comment: There is no issue in using a library. Main goal is to retrieve the image in its original form in python http server.